# Android: path of specific file from a list

Tags: java, android, listview, path

I have a list of wav file in a folder in external storage. I display this list with ListView, this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final StringBuffer stringbuff = new StringBuffer();

    private ListView mainListView ;  
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  
        ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();  

        File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File file = new File(storage,"/folder/");

        if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
            for (String s : file.list()) {
                stringbuffer.append(s + " ");
                List.addAll( Arrays.asList(s) );
            }
        }

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, R.id.rowTextView,List); 
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );  

    }
```

I want that the click of  a button the path of selected file. How can I do it?

Comment: Consider using Custom ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

The following code will show the files path with toast

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        String filepath = new File(storage + "/folder/"+ List.get(arg2)).getAbsolutePath();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filepath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but where I must add this part, because I want by selecting a file in the list, with a button, I see the path of this file

Comment: just add it after mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter ); when you click a row you will see adress

Answer (score 0):

You need to add OnItemClickListener

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener openSelection = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
            String p = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            Toast.makeText(UploadFilePage.this, p, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
};

mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(openSelection);
```